# rails cron job overlap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron

I am using heroku scheduler with every 10 minutes run a task. The task is doing sth like below. I am thinking about how to prevent the next job overlap with the current one. Are there anythings can prevent cron job overlap problem?

```
task force_close: :environment do
    #get all unvoted wine_question
    questions = Question.where(closed: false)
    puts "Total #{questions} of wine_question will be closed"

    finish_count = 0
    questions.each do |question|
      begin
        question.force_close!
        finish_count += 1
      rescue StandardError => bang
        puts "question #{self.id} error when running #{bang}"
      end
    end

    puts "Total #{finish_count} of question was closed"
  end
```

Comment: What does `the next job get the undone active record to call force_close! again` mean?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I have changed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 ways.

First,
Create checked field on Question. like `force_closed:boolean`
and touch force_closed field when call `force_close!` method
so you can find questions by `where(closed: false, force_closed: false)`

Second,
Create batch history table. columns should are `task_name` and `run_at`
and save runnging time info in batch history table,

```
# last line of task
BatchHistory.create(task_name: 'force_close', run_at: Time.now)
```

Comment: Thanks. The second one should be better for my case.